# How can i terminate for loop with user input (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I am trying to get odd numbers with for loop in javascript but i want to terminate the loop with user input and i cant do this, can you help me friends.

i want " x<7" to  be this "x < input"

```
<html>

<head>

<body>

<input id="numbers" type="number">
<button onclick="odd()">Odd Numbers</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function odd() {
var text = " ";
var x;
for ( x = 1; x < 7; x+= 2) {
    text += x + " ";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =+ text;
}
</script>

</body>

</head>

</html>
```

Comment: show us your own implemented code.

Comment: Hello, please take a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and help us help you by providing a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have attempted thus far.

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE

Now that you have told us what you want, here's my updated code:

Basically it just sets a limit and changes it with the change of the div

```html
<html>

<head>

<body>

<input id="numbers" type="number" onChange="change()">
<button onclick="odd()">Odd Numbers</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var lim=7;
function change() {
    lim = document.getElementById("numbers").value;
}
function odd() {
var text = " ";
var x;
for ( x = 1; x < lim; x+=2) {
    text += x + " ";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += text;
}
</script>

</body>

</head>

</html>
```

## Old code

You can use `setInterval` and `clearInterval` to achieve this:

```js
var i = 1;
var myInt = setInterval(function(){
document.getElementById("div").innerHTML += i;
i+=2;
}, 100);
```

```html
<button onClick="clearInterval(myInt)">STOP</button>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying for, This looks at your user input and if it is larger than your starting iterator it loops.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.go');

button.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const input = document.getElementById('numbers');
  const output = document.getElementById('demo');
  
  if (input.value == 0) { return; }
  
  for (let i = 0, len = input.value; i <= len; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 1) {  
      output.textContent += i.toString();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>

<body>

<input id="numbers" type="number">
<button class='go'>Odd Numbers</button>
<p id="demo"></p>


</body>

</head>

</html>
```